# Bash: change environment temporarily

Tags: 10.10, bash

I am using a dev tool which supplies a script that sets environment variables. If I source the script the environment is modified for the duration of the bash secession. In order to revert the changes made by that script I need to restart the terminal. Is there a way to do it without restarting or opening new bash session?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do it in a subshell:

```
$ (. /path/to/envsetup.sh; runtool)
```

If there's just a handful of environment changes, you can do them on the command line:

```
$ FOO=a BAR=b runtool # FOO and BAR will be set only for runtool
```

You can also use an actual subshell if you anticipate doing a number of things:

```
$ bash
$ : this is a subshell
$ . /path/to/envsetup.sh
$ thing1
$ thing2
$ : ...
$ exit
$ : this is the original shell
```

You may want to include `$SHLVL` in your `$PS1` for the latter, so it's easier to tell that you're in a subshell.  I also check for a (nonstandard) environment variable `$PSYS` and print it if set, as a sort of "label" for the environment.

Comment: H! could you explain this $ (. /path/to/envsetup.sh; runtool). Thanks!
P.S. I need the new env vars to stay for a while and then go back to the old env.

Comment: Enclosing something in parentheses runs it in a temporary subshell.  It's kind of like a fast version of my final example, all squeezed into a single line.  (The `$` is the prompt in all of the above examples.) In your case, it sounds like you want the final version with the full subshell.

Comment: How about: type bash then set env and after dode using the dev-tool type exit?

Comment: That is what the final example does.  (As I mentioned before, the `$` is the prompt / `$PS1`, not some special shell syntax.)